# how can i select childern node in flex tree component?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tree, flashbuilder4, flash-builder4.5

If i want check parent node checkbox means below childerns checkbox will select automatic .

this is my code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void    {
            httpTree.send();

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="httpTree" url="Assets/World.xml"  
                   resultFormat="e4x" useProxy="false" />
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:Tree dataProvider="{httpTree.lastResult.department}"
         id="treeTree" labelField="@name"   
         itemRenderer="com.ItemRenderForTree"  width="160" height="200" />
```

itemRenderer  file

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function checkboxSelectHandler(event:Event):void
        {

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />            
    <s:State name="hovered" />
    <s:State name="selected" />
</s:states>
<s:HGroup left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Rect id="indentationSpacer" width="{treeListData.indent}" percentHeight="100" alpha="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Group id="disclosureGroup">
        <s:BitmapImage source="{treeListData.disclosureIcon}" visible="{treeListData.hasChildren}" />
    </s:Group>
    <s:BitmapImage source="{treeListData.icon}" />
    <s:CheckBox change="checkboxSelectHandler(event)" />
    <s:Label id="labelField" text="{treeListData.label}" paddingTop="2"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

[image: i want out like this]

any one can help thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Use tree dataDescriptor to access children nodes of clicked parent node. Maybe that could help? Does your three data have a selected property in datamodel?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what I've always called a Schrodinger Check Box. Here is a same piece of code, including a working demo and the PNG resources for the checkbox over at adobe.
[Schrodinger Check Box](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_A_3_state_checkbox_in_a_TreeItemRenderer-545.html)